# Update Magento extension using ssh to extract .tgz tar file

Tags: shell, magento, command-line, ssh, extract

I am trying to update a module to a newer version. In the past I have manually uploaded each file carefully into the new directory and overwritten older files using FTP. However I wanted to use SSH to try and do this more easily and without any file permission problems. 
I have:

- Uploaded the .tgz file to the root folder (/http) on the server
- Logged into the server via SSH
- Changed the directory to the correct directory
- Run the following command: `tar -zxvf fishpig_splash.tgz`

In the command line I was then given a list of all the files that had been extracted. However if I use FTP to go to any of these files I can see that they are still the older version and have not been overwritten.

I was expecting that the files would extract into the correct directories and overwrite any that already existed. I have tested the extraction by creating a temporary directory and extracting into that and everything worked fine.

Is there another part to this script I need to use to overwrite the files?

Thanks
Glynn

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue between the user your website is running as and the user you're logged in via SSH as?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was just me being stupid! When extracting the tar file there was a subfolder within it for the extension, I completely missed it. I just went down a level in the file and zipped up the contents only then extracted them at the root and everything worked fine. Thanks for the help though!